# How can I fix my div so that it moves upwards when images are rescaled

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've just inserted an image slider into my homepage that shrinks content when the browser window is resized.
My problem however is that I have a div underneath it that doesn't move upwards when the image slider resizes itself, so i'm left with a large section of blank-space.

Is this something to do with the CSS of the div underneath the slider?

HTML

```
<div id="slider1_container">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading">
            <div id="loadingchild1">
            </div>
            <div id="loadingchild2">
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div id="slides" u="slides">
            <div>
                <div class="image1">
                    <img  u="image" src="C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\iMac-Mockup.png" />
                </div>


                <div class="toptext">
                    RED
                </div>
                <div class="bottomtext">
                    Build your slider with anything, includes image, content, text, html, photo, picture
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="image1">
                    <img u="image" src="C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\iPad-Mockup.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="toptext">
                    Red
                </div>
                <div class="bottomtext">
                    Build your slider with anything, includes image, content, text, html, photo, picture
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="image1">
                    <img u="image" src="C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\iPhone-Mockup.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="toptext">
                    Red
                </div>
                <div class="bottomtext">
                    Build your slider with anything, includes image, content, text, html, photo, picture
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="ContentWrapper">
        <div id="FreeLanceText">
            <p>A Freelance Web Designer/ Developer in Chester full of Fresh ideas,</p>
            <p>I create Affordable and Stylish Websites to help your Business Online</p>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#ContentWrapper
{

width:100%; /*1920px*/
height:100px;
background-color:#000000;
color:white;
margin-top:485px;
}

#FreeLanceText
{

    text-align:center;
    font-size:180%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a top margin of 485px set on `#ContentWrapper`. I'm guessing this is because you're using absolute positioning on your slider and you need to leave a gap large enough for that.

Instead, put things back in a regular document flow (relative positioning) and set a margin on `#ContentWrapper` solely to create an appropriate gap between it and the slider.